# Insert data into the table from the finished procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server

How can I insert data into the table from the finished procedure, which was created using other scripts (data are on the rows in the results). This solutions was necessarily because I must concatenate coordinates.

One of the finishing step is:

```
select concat ('insert into table_shop ([IU], [ODD]) values ', data1)as PasteDat
from #tmp_07
```

In value data1 I have upload data.

When finished scripts I have result a lot of rows. 
For example:

```
insert into table_shop ([IU], [ODD]) values ('A0001', 'D08')
insert into table_shop ([IU], [ODD]) values ('Agw44', 'D10')
insert into table_shop ([IU], [ODD]) values ('A5888', 'D18')
.
.
.
```

Now what I do is copying rows and paste on the other new query. Is there a more elegant way to do it in bulk?

Comment: give more information

Comment: I added more information. Its enough? What do you specifically imagine?

Answer (score 0):

Hope this helps

```
Use AdventureWorks2012

GO
Create Table #temp --table into which we need to insert
(
[DepartmentID] int,
[Name] varchar(50)
)
GO
Create PROCEDURE SP_ResultSet --SP which returns a result set
as
Select  [DepartmentID]
        ,[Name]
from [HumanResources].[Department]
GO
Insert into #temp EXEC SP_ResultSet -- serves the purpose
GO
Select * from #temp order by [DepartmentID]
```

Comment: Doesnt work, because i need use INSERT INTO statement.